# Not able to merge two columns in SQL Server while printing

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, datagrid, concatenation

I want to print two columns of a table in a desired format. I tried with the below format but it's giving error saying

> Error converting data type varchar
>   to bigint.

This is my query:

```
Select  ClassID + ' .' + ClassSectionID AS Class 
from ClassSectionMaster  
ORDER BY Class
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't like the fact you're trying to combine a column of type bigint (ClassID/ClassSectionID) with a string, ' .'

I'm assuming you want the output to be formatted like "9.6" and that strings are acceptable.

You have to use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to change the datatype to VARCHAR(x) to do this sort of combination.

```
SELECT CAST(ClassID AS VARCHAR(x)) + ' .' + CAST(ClassSectionID AS VARCHAR(y)) 
    AS Class
FROM ClassSectionMaster ORDER BY Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select (Convert(nvarchar(10), ClassID) + ' .' + Convert(nvarchar(10), ClassSectionID)) AS Class 
from ClassSectionMaster  
ORDER BY Class
```